# Possible to have multiple conditions in MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql

I would like to find out what are the emails that are in my database that are not from @Gmail.com and @Yahoo.com and the email has more than 10 characters. Is this query possible?

I only managed to find out what emails are not from gmail :

```
SELECT *  FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_email` NOT LIKE '%@GMAIL.COM'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use `and` to combine multiple conditions

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users 
WHERE user_email NOT LIKE '%@GMAIL.COM'
  AND user_email NOT LIKE '%@YAHOO.COM'
  AND CHAR_LENGTH(user_email) > 10
```

Comment: you cant use length. length give you the count of bytes used for the string. you can use **CHAR_LENGTH** instead try this: **SELECT length('Üäß'), CHAR_LENGTH('Üäß');** to see the difference

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.